# An incompatible version 1.1.12 of the APR based Apache Tomcat Native library is installed, while Tomcat requires version 1.1.17

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, tomcat7

I downloaded Apache Tomcat 7.x. When I add this Tomcat in Eclipse I get this error:

```
Jan 25, 2011 3:21:05 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
SEVERE: An incompatible version 1.1.12 of the APR based Apache Tomcat Native library is installed, while Tomcat requires version 1.1.17 
Jan 25, 2011 3:21:05 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
SEVERE: An incompatible version 1.1.12 of the APR based Apache Tomcat Native library is installed, while Tomcat requires version 1.1.17 
Jan 25, 2011 3:21:05 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
SEVERE: An incompatible version 1.1.12 of the APR based Apache Tomcat Native library is installed, while Tomcat requires version 1.1.17 
Jan 25, 2011 3:21:05 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
SEVERE: An incompatible version 1.1.12 of the APR based Apache Tomcat Native library is installed, while Tomcat requires version 1.1.17 
Jan 25, 2011 3:21:05 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
SEVERE: An incompatible version 1.1.12 of the APR based Apache Tomcat Native library is installed, while Tomcat requires version 1.1.17 
Jan 25, 2011 3:21:08 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jan 25, 2011 3:21:08 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jan 25, 2011 3:21:08 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 3054 ms
Jan 25, 2011 3:21:08 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jan 25, 2011 3:21:08 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.6
Jan 25, 2011 3:21:08 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jan 25, 2011 3:21:08 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jan 25, 2011 3:21:08 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 251 ms
```

How can I solve this problem?

When I open the `localhost:8080/manager/html` it shows the following error:

```
HTTP Status 404 - /manager/html

type Status report

message /manager/html

description The requested resource (/manager/html) is not available.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.6
```

Answer (score 5):

The first error certainly sounds like a version mismatch.  The APR library is a library linked in at runtime based on your path (which itself can be based on where you execute Tomcat from).  It sounds like you have the APR library for Tomcat 6.  It's possible that Eclipse is providing this APR library.

Tomcat ships with an APR library but in order to ease installation Tomcat doesn't automatically modify the path to point at the APR library.  The Eclipse Tomcat integration may (I'm not sure on this one, haven't used the integration before) include the APR libraries to make it easier to use Tomcat.

Check and make sure that Eclipse isn't configured to use an earlier version of Tomcat and if it is, either upgrade Eclipse to Tomcat 7 or downgrade Tomcat to the version specified in Eclipse.

If you can't figure it out then you don't necessarily have to worry about it at the moment.  Tomcat should work anyways without the APR libraries.  The only benefit you will get from the APR libraries is increased performance and since this is probably the start of your project that doesn't have to be worked out right away.

The second issue, the /manager/ page, could be Tomcat configuration.  Tomcat won't actually display the manager page (and it will give you that error) unless users have been configured with [manager permissions](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/manager-howto.html).

Try going to just / (i.e. http://localhost:8080), that page should load regardless of user configuration.

Answer (score 3):

In my case I had inadvertently installed the APR library when I install once Tomcat locally on my Linux using the package manager. On Debian/Ubuntu this installed the APR package for a different Tomcat version (the one bundled with your distribution) which caused this error.

After simply

```
sudo apt-get purge libtcnative-1
```

The error was gone.